# react.js indexDB large data store.put performance issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storing-data

I have an array of objects that can have millions of rows. I am trying to store it in indexDB and I can do this successfully but it has some performance issues on the "put" method. The reason is because I am having to loop over every index and put it in indexDB individually. Is there a way to simply dump the entire array in here? here is my code...

```
    var indexDB;
    indexDB = window.indexedDB; 
    var open = indexedDB.open("HistoricalDB");
    open.onupgradeneeded = function(){
    let db = open.result;
    let store = db.createObjectStore("HistoricalTable", {keyPath: "id"});
    let index = store.createIndex("CIndex", ["time", "value"]);
    };
    open.onsuccess = function(){
        let db = open.result;
        let tx = db.transaction("HistoricalTable", "readwrite");
        let store = tx.objectStore("HistoricalTable");
        let index = store.index("CIndex");
        for (let i=0; i<allHistoricalData.length-1; i++){
            store.put(allHistoricalData[i]);
        }
        let getAll = store.getAll();
        getAll.onsuccess = function(){
            console.log(getAll.result)
        }
        tx.oncomplete = function(){
            db.close();
        };
    }
```

Here is what is killing me....

```
        for (let i=0; i<allHistoricalData.length-1; i++){
            store.put(allHistoricalData[i]);
        }
```

Is there a way to do store.put(allHistoricalData) instead of store.put(allHistoricalData[i] in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexDB can store any kind of javascript clonable data, so you should be able to simply store you array as a whole.

I see you are creating an index and using that to store the values. IndexDB indexes are used to look up data in a store but should not be used to stored data itself.

What you want to do is put data directly in the store like so:

```js
var open = window.indexedDB.open('HistoricalDB');

open.onupgradeneeded = function () {
  let db = open.result;
  db.createObjectStore('HistoricalTable');
};

open.onsuccess = function () {
  let db = open.result;
  let tx = db.transaction('HistoricalTable', 'readwrite');
  let store = tx.objectStore('HistoricalTable');
  let request = store.put(allHistoricalData, 'DATA');

  request.onsuccess = function () {
    console.log('success!');
  };
  request.onerror = function () {
    console.log(request.error);
  };
};
```

Comment: Should I create the store like this then...        let store = db.createObjectStore("HistoricalTable");

Comment: Yes, if you are not using keyPaths then you don't have to specify any options.

Comment: Be aware that if you are storing millions of rows then the put function will probably take a while. What this is doing is letting that process happen asynchronously so your application can continue to function.

Comment: Can you show the complete code? I am still having issues. My compile crashed on me.

Comment: updated answer to show complete code to store data, I'll let you handle the data retrieving